# How to create n number of UIButton programmatically in UITableView Cell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

I am trying to create one `UITableView` with n number of buttons depends on backend JSON data.

I have attached an image, i know how to create UIButtons on `UITableViewCell` but i don't know how to place them correctly inside `UITableViewCell`.

`UIButton` for `UITableViewCell`

```
UIButton *continuebtn = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 100, view1.frame.size.width-20, 40)];
[continuebtn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
[continuebtn setTitle:@"Continue" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
continuebtn.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
continuebtn.layer.borderWidth =1.0;
continuebtn.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
[continuebtn setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

[image]

How to  place  'n' number of `UIButton`  on `UITableViewCell` ?? `UIButton` width depends on its text content

Comment: cell would be scrollable horizontally?

Comment: no , not like that but cell height should increase to fit all button automatically..thats the problem

Comment: so you get data tha how many buttons you want to add like 3,4,5 etcc ?

Comment: each button would be placed as horizontal slabs or they are to be arranged   like in collection view?

Comment: yes correct, then i will use for loop to generate UIButtons

Comment: @Usama not horizondally..pls check attached pic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a better answer myself.
Please check this code.

```
  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    [cell addSubview:[self addView:indexPath.row]];
    return cell;
}


-(UIView *)addView:(NSInteger)row{

    UIView *progView;
    progView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,cell.frame.size.width,cell.frame.size.height)];
    progView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    progView.tag = i;    
    progView.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin);

    int x,y;
    x=10;y=10;
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc]init];
        NSString *myString=@"Dynamic";
        [button setTitle:myString forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        CGSize stringsize = [myString sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]];
        [button setFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,stringsize.width+40, stringsize.height+20)];
        x+=stringsize.width+50;
        NSLog(@"%d-%f",x,progView.frame.size.width);

        if(x>progView.frame.size.width){
            y+=50;
            x=10;
        }

        button.layer.borderWidth =1.0;
        button.layer.borderColor = [UIColor greenColor].CGColor;
        [button setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button setTag:i]; 
        [progView addSubview:button];
    }

    return progView;
}
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 200;
}
```

Comment: Returning cell height a constant value of 200, will this not truncate your cells if there are more buttons  which goes beyond the size of 200?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to put buttons vertically in a cell, use following suggestions:

Your `UITableviewCell`'s height would depend upon number of buttons. Implement `heightForRowAtIndexPath` method as following:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return 100.0f + (buttonsArray.count*buttonHeight+buttonsHeightSeparator);

    //change 100.0f with height that is required for cell without buttons
    //buttonHeight is a static float representing value for height of each button
    //buttonHeightSeparator is a static float representing separation distance between two buttons
}
```

In your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, you can create buttons using following code:

```
for(int i=0; i<buttonsArray.count; i++) {
    UIButton *continuebtn = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 100+i*(buttonHeight+buttonsHeightSeparator), view1.frame.size.width-20, 40)];
    [continuebtn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
    [continuebtn setTitle:@"Continue" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    continuebtn.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
    continuebtn.layer.borderWidth =1.0;
    continuebtn.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    [continuebtn setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [continuebtn addTarget:self action:@selector(continueBtnPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; //add target to receive button tap event
    [continuebtn setTag:i]; //to identify button
    [cell.contentView addSubview:continuebtn]; //add button to cell
}
```

Comment: In case if my UITableView cell have different number of UIButtons in cell so should create multiple sections or should i check for indexpath.row in UITableview?

Comment: check for indexPath.row both in `heightForRowAtIndexPath` and `cellForRowAtIndexPath` methods to create buttons in different cells.

Comment: this creating buttons vertically independent of textsize