# Monotouch - Use a for loop to create UILabels programmatically below each other

Tags: uitableview, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I know the solution may be fairly simple, but I'm having challenges with positioning these views.

I'm trying to create `UILabels` dynamically, within a `UITableViewCell`. The number of `UILabels` is unknown at compile time.

Based on the size of my list of data, I would like to create a new `UILabel`, one below another and populate the data at each index in the list, on the respective `UILabel`.

Because these are created inside a `UITableViewCell`, I would like them to be positioned below the cell's `TextLabel`.

Currently, my new `UILabels` are all stacked on top of each other, above the `TextLabel` and I can't seem to position them correctly.

```
public void UpdateCell(List<Records> allRecords,List<string> otherInfo)
    {
        try{

            UILabel label = new UILabel();

            myRecords = allRecords;

            for(int i = 0; i < myRecords.Count;i++)
            {

             if(i == 0)  

            //Position the first one below the cell's TextLabel
            {
                string time = myRecords[i].ResponseTime;

                label.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(TextLabel.Frame.X + 10,TextLabel.Frame.Y + TextLabel.Frame.Height + 10,ContentView.Frame.Width,19);
                label.Font = UIFont.FromName ("HelveticaNeueLTStd-ThCn", 18f);
                label.TextColor = UIColor.DarkGray;
                label.Text = string.Format("-  {0},  {1}",otherInfo[i],time);
                ContentView.AddSubview(label);

                }else{

                  string responseTime = myRecords[i].ResponseTime;

                  //Position subsequent views below the first label
                    UILabel label1 = new UILabel();
                    label1.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(label.Frame.X,label.Frame.Bottom + 5,ContentView.Frame.Width,19);
                    label1.Font = UIFont.FromName ("HelveticaNeueLTStd-ThCn", 18f);
                    label1.TextColor = UIColor.DarkGray;
                    label1.Text = string.Format("-  {0},  {1}",otherInfo[i],responseTime);
                    ContentView.AddSubview(label1);

                    }

                }
          }

        }catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine (ex.Message + ex.StackTrace);

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the answer on SO here : [How to create n number of UIButton programmatically in UITableView Cell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33496982/how-to-create-n-number-of-uibutton-programmatically-in-uitableview-cell)

I was able to come up with a solution like this:

```
   public void UpdateCell(List<Records> allRecords,List<string> otherInfo)
   {
    try{

        UILabel label = new UILabel();

        myRecords = allRecords;

        for(int i = 0; i < myRecords.Count;i++)
        {

        string time = myRecords[i].ResponseTime;

            label.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(45,TextLabel.Frame.Height + i *(labelSize + spacing),ContentView.Frame.Width,19);
            label.Font = UIFont.FromName ("HelveticaNeueLTStd-ThCn", 18f);
            label.TextColor = UIColor.DarkGray;
            label.Text = string.Format("-  {0},  {1}",otherInfo[i],time);
            ContentView.AddSubview(label);

         }

            }

        }catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine (ex.Message + ex.StackTrace);

        }

    }
```